# JTable cell editor number format

Tags: java, swing, jtable, number-formatting, tablecelleditor

I need to show numbers in jTable with exact 2 decimal places. To accomplish this I have created a custom cell editor as:

```
public class NumberCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public NumberCellEditor(){
        super(new JFormattedTextField());
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JFormattedTextField editor = (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);

        if (value!=null){
            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");
            editor.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(numberFormat)));
            Number num = (Number) value;  
            String text = numberFormat.format(num);
            editor.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            editor.setText(text);
        }
        return editor;
    }
}
```

This cell editor works perfect for English locale where a dot is used as decimal point. But in German locale, it doesn't accept values with comma as a decimal point. Please let me know where there is a problem in my code. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is how I got it working:

```
public class NumberCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
public NumberCellEditor(){
    super(new JFormattedTextField());
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    JFormattedTextField editor = (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);

    if (value instanceof Number){
        Locale myLocale = Locale.getDefault(); 

        NumberFormat numberFormatB = NumberFormat.getInstance(myLocale);
        numberFormatB.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormatB.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormatB.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);

        editor.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
                        new NumberFormatter(numberFormatB)));

        editor.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        editor.setValue(value);
    }
    return editor;
}

@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    try {
        // try to get the value
        this.getCellEditorValue();
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    // get content of textField
    String str = (String) super.getCellEditorValue();
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // try to parse a number
    try {
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Number n = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(str, pos);
        if (pos.getIndex() != str.length()) {
            throw new ParseException(
                    "parsing incomplete", pos.getIndex());
        }

        // return an instance of column class
        return new Float(n.floatValue());

    } catch (ParseException pex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(pex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've already up-voted your question, but I wish I could do so again. Thanks for posting that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the locale to your advantage:

```
  //Locale myLocale = Locale.GERMANY;  //... or better, the current Locale

  Locale myLocale = Locale.getDefault(); // better still

  NumberFormat numberFormatB = NumberFormat.getInstance(myLocale);
  numberFormatB.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  numberFormatB.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
  numberFormatB.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);

  edit.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
                    new NumberFormatter(numberFormatB)));
```

Comment: @StanislavL did you once time need to set Locale for JComponents same Locale as return all todays native OS by defalut?

Comment: I have changed my code according to the above block, but I am still facing the problem. When double-clicked, the edit field shows value properly in locale aware format (it shows comma as decimal point for German locale), but it does not accept an edited value with comma as a decimal point (when just shows the old value when we try to edit it to something that contains comma as point)

Comment: @Statue: please consider creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), a small compilable and runnable program that requires no outside resources (for example images or database) and which demonstrates your problem and then post it as an edit to your question.

Comment: I have managed to get it working perfectly by overriding getCellEditorValue and stopEditing methods from DefaultCellEditor.

Comment: @Statue: Congrats!! I'd love to see your successful cell editor code. Can you post it for us?

Comment: Sure, should I post the code here in comments? Or is there a more appropriate place to post it?

Comment: @Statue: you can't post in comments. Instead post it as an edit to your original post.

Answer (score 2):

for example

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;


public class SubstDouble2DecimalRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int precision = 0;
    private Number numberValue;
    private NumberFormat nf;

    public SubstDouble2DecimalRenderer(int p_precision) {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        precision = p_precision;
        nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(p_precision);  
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(p_precision);
        nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);  
    }

    public SubstDouble2DecimalRenderer() {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number)) {
            numberValue = (Number) value;
            value = nf.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
        }
        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("\\d*([\\.,\\,]\\d{0,2})?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `#,###,###,##0.00` with  `#.###.###.##0,00`