# java bindings - how to bind a float to a jtable without getting -0.0 values?

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable

I have a JTable and I use binding (JTableBinding) to bind a list to it
In the object I use I have a getter and setter to each bind member.
This ofcourse is loaded with reflection.

My problem is that sometimes I get -0.0 instead of plain zero in the display.
How can I format it to be alwayz 0 when it is -0.0?
Thannks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a primitive float value be -0.0? What does that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724031/how-can-a-primitive-float-value-be-0-0-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: Same question was asked 10 minutes ago

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Almost identical, but here the question revolves around how to apply the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724031/how-can-a-primitive-float-value-be-0-0-what-does-that-mean/6724051#6724051).

Comment: Exactly. Didn't want to ask it in the comments and I thought it would assist to open new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `JTableBinding`, but a suitable implementation of `TableCellRenderer` may suffice. The relevant tutorial is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), and there's an example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: agreed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556651/jtable-cell-editor-number-format/6556681#6556681 (:- but hardcoded to instanceof.Double:-) +1

Answer (score 0):

add a special case to check if your float is 0 or -0 then print 0